# Converting object_setInstanceVariable() to ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I wish to convert an instance of

```
object_setInstanceVariable(self, [key UTF8String], *(id**)addr);
```

to ARC. When I try to use Xcode built-in Objective-C ARC converter I get the following error:

> 'object_setInstanceVariable' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

How should I handle this problem? I know I can put --fno-objc-arc as Compiler flag, but I would very much like to use ARC instead, if it's possible (I have a lot of targets that I otherwise would have to manually change the Compiler flag for).

(The code is originally taken from [NSObject+NSCoding and Archiver](https://github.com/greenisus/NSObject-NSCoding) by Mike Mayo at Rackspace Mobile Apps)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html

The only other method to do this is:

```
void object_setIvar(id object, Ivar ivar, id value);
```

You need the `Ivar` value beforehand, which can be obtained via `class_getInstanceVariable(Class class, char* name)`.

Overall this will achieve the same effect as before, whilst now being ARC compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your input! If there's no better solution the coming days I'm giving you the accept :)

Comment: @WDUK: `class_getInstanceVariable` seems to work and get you the `Ivar` even when ARC is enabled.