# Dynamically creating getters and setters for @dynamic properties causing infinite loop

Tags: c++, objective-c

Currenlty I have an issue with ocmock for unit testing because some @dynamic properties have no getters or setters when being mocked. I'm using `class_addmethod` to add the getters and setters for all @dynamic properties. My issue is this

```
void accessorSetter(id self, SEL _cmd, id newValue)
{
    NSString *method = NSStringFromSelector(_cmd);
    id value = [newValue copy];
// remove set prefix from string
    NSString *anID = [[method stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3) withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
    anID = [anID stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[anID substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] lowercaseString]];
    [self setValue:value forKey:anID];
}
```

causes an infite loops since setValue calls the setter. I think I can use c++ syntax like `self->somevar = value` to avoid the infinite loop. My question is how do I do this assigment when the name of the variable is a string? anID is the name of the variable and i can't do `self->anID = aValue` cuz anID is not a property. How do I convert it to a variable name? Or how can I set the property without creating the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `object_setInstanceVariable` or `object_setIvar` and `object_getInstanceVariable`. You can take a look at the [Objective C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html) for more information.

**EDIT:**
If you are using ARC, you can't use `object_setInstanceVariable`. You'll be stuck with `object_setIvar`.

**EDIT 2:** See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196727/converting-object-setinstancevariable-to-arc) answer if you are using ARC.

Example usage:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface Test : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *test;
@end
@implementation Test
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    self.test = @"asdasd";
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setTest:(NSString*)test {
    Ivar var_desc = object_getInstanceVariable(self, [@"_test" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL);
    NSLog(@"Setting _test to %@", test);
    object_setIvar(self, var_desc, test);
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test *tst = [[Test alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"prop: %@", tst.test);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2013-12-11 18:19:32.038 ivar_tst[97090:507] Setting _test to asdasd
2013-12-11 18:19:32.040 ivar_tst[97090:507] prop: asdasd
```

Comment: Great idea. Still seeming to cause an infinite loop. I got the ARC methods but I can see using breakpoints that is calling itself over and over. Not sure if there's a way around this but it seems like you can't override a setter method at runtime.

Comment: Your problem is definitely somewhere else... see my edited answer with an example, which is overriding the setter and using the `object_setIvar` without causing infinite loops.

Comment: You can also see this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819092/how-can-i-add-properties-to-an-object-at-runtime) as an example of adding properties at runtime, which is also using `object_getInstanceVariable` and `object_setIvar`.

Comment: Does your example work with `@dynamic` properties? I think my issue is related to using `@dynamic`.

Comment: Ya just saw that I was doing `class_getInstanceVariable(self, [anID cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` which broke but `class_getInstanceVariable(object_getClass(self), [anID cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` worked better

Comment: See the answer for the question I added in my previous comment, there's a very nice example there.

Comment: Setter seems to be working. Xcode is crashing on ever po statement but lets be honest xcode 5 isn't that stable anyways. Thanks ivan